# unable to connect to server "IIS Express" or "https" while add area in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localhost, .net-7.0

I recently used Visual Studio 7.0 to develop a new site.
With all the challenges I had so far, a new challenge has been created.
When the website layer is intact and without changes, you can view the default pages in the browser using IIS. But when I try to create an Area, I can no longer see my pages in the browser.
It should be noted that during the creation of a new area, I did not change any of the configurations of the lunchsetting.json file, and the only change is adding the endpoint path to the program.cs program file.
Also, in another separate file with the same specifications and errors, I changed the ports of the localhost and deleted the configuration file in the .vs folder as suggested by one of Stack Overflow's comments.

I appreciate your help in advance

Program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

builder.Services.AddMvc();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
 {
   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
   // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, 
   see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
   app.UseHsts();
 }

 app.UseHttpsRedirection();

 app.UseStaticFiles();

 app.UseRouting();

 app.UseAuthorization();

 app.MapRazorPages();

 app.RunAsync();

 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
 );
});
```

lunchsetting.json :

```
   {
      "iisSettings": {
     "windowsAuthentication": false,
     "anonymousAuthentication": true,
     "iisExpress": {
       "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:16264",
       "sslPort": 44309
   }
   },
     "profiles": {
       "http": {
       "commandName": "Project",
       "dotnetRunMessages": true,
       "launchBrowser": true,
       "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5053",
       "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
  },
     "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7005;http://localhost:5053",
      "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
 },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `app.Run();` or `await app.RunAsync();`.

Besides, you need call endpoints middleware before `await app.RunAsync();`, and it suggests using top level route registrations instead of `UseEndpoints` in .NET 7:

```
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

await app.RunAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Rena. With your help, my problem was solved